# Nhibernate 3.1 upgradation nhibernate-mapping issue No Persister for Exception

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to upgrade my project from Nhibernate 1.0 to 3.1 and I am experiencing an error which Says the following:-
NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for: 
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionFactoryImpl.cs:line 470
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName, Object obj) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 2728

I get this error on Session.save() in the code.

The configuration is written programatically and the build action of the.hbm.xml file is embedded source. The configuration is builded properly but the session.save() is throwing the error.

Comment: This error usually appears when the mapping file is not loaded. There is not really much information in your question.

Comment: The configuration is written programatically and the build action of the.hbm.xml file is embedded source. The configuration is builded properly but the session.save() is throwing the error

Comment: Additional Information:- Database used Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue. The issue was with IloggingInterceptor. If the session was created with the interceptor it was throwing issues. For a normal session without interceptor the code is working fine. Now It would be great if some one could help me implementing the methods in the IloggingInteceptor, methods like OnPrepareStatement, GetEntity etc., thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

When you call Session.save() that will be the first time you know if you have a mapping problem.  Not enough information here but check your namespace.  If you have it, use Reflector to ensure you are referencing the correct namespace for your domain objects in your mapping files.

In regards to information:  since I think it's a namespace issue, is this a C# or VB project (I say this because you have to be careful with the namespaces between the two types.  It's one of those "gotchas")? Can you show us a snippet of your NHibernate configuration?  A lot has changed since NHibernate 1, double check to ensure you are using the latest conventions?

Comment: I need to solve this problem what more information is needed, can  you please let me know?

Comment: I am using c# code and here is a snippet of my programmatic confirguration  . properties["connection.provider"] = "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider";
                properties["dialect"] = "NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect";
                properties["connection.driver_class"] = "NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver";
                properties["connection.connection_string"] = ConnectionString;
                properties["show_sql"] = "true";
                properties["proxyfactory.factory_class"] = "NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Lin

Comment: continued:-

 properties["proxyfactory.factory_class"] = "NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu";
                properties["hbm2ddl.keywords"]="none";
                properties["bytecode.provider"] = "lcg";

Comment: Resolved the issue. The issue was with IloggingInterceptor. If the session was created with the interceptor it was throwing issues. For a normal session without interceptor the code is working fine. Now It would be great if some one could help me implementing the methods in the IloggingInteceptor, methods like OnPrepareStatement, GetEntity etc., thanks for all your answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot to will and stefan for the help rendered.